# Determining precisely where $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $ converges uniformly

Tags: complex-analysis

I already proved in which discs the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $ converges (with summation by parts, dirichlets test, and Abels formula). These are all the discs $D(z,r)$$\subset$$D(z,1)$ and $D(z,1)-${1}.

What about uniform convergence now? What I've found so far is that since   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(|\frac{z^n}{n}|\right)$ converges, then in  all $D(z,r)$$\subset$ $D(z,1)$ the series will converge uniformly -$Weierstrass$-. But what happens on $D(z,1)$ disc?

EDIT:I found the solution is this problem. Let $0<r<1$ we are gonna search what happens in discs $D(z,r)$ and $D(z,1)$

- $D(z,r)$ we see that |$\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right)-$ $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $| = |$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $| $\leq$ $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \left(\frac{|z^n|}{n}\right) $ $\leq$ $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \left(|r^n|\right) $ = $\frac{r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ $\rightarrow$$0$ the definition of uniform convergance is satisfied
- $D(z,1)$ we see that $sup_{|z|<1}$|$\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right)-$ $\sum_{i=2n}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $| $\geq$ |$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right)-$ $\sum_{i=2n}^\infty \left(\frac{z^n}{n}\right) $|$_{z=1-(1/n)}$ $\geq$ $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2n}$ $\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) $ $\geq$ $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{2n}$$\frac{n}{2n}$ $\rightarrow$$\frac{1}{2e^2}$ when n$\rightarrow$$\infty$ that goes against the definition of uniform convergance

So it converges uniformly in all discs $D(0,r)$ , r$\in$$(0,1)$

Comment: please edit your question for clarity.  As it stands, it does not make any sense.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: The Question has now been edited, and the proper conclusion has been outlined by the OP.  That is, this series converges uniformly on any closed disk $D(0,r)$ when (and only when) $0\lt r \lt 1$.